# Frame Buffer Image Viewer (FBI) Failing when Executed as Process - Java

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to use the Linux FBI utility to write a few .jpg images to the framebuffer on a Raspberry Pi 3 from Java.

From the command line everything works as expected. My java application runs fine until I attempt to run the following line of code (no Java errors by the way):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo fbi -T 1 -d /dev/fb0 -a -noverbose -t 1 -cachemem 0 /home/pi/Desktop/*.jpg");
```

The black loading screen for FBI does display when this process is executed so I know that it's executing properly, but FBI responds with an error stating `/home/pi/Desktop/*.jpg Loading Failed`. I've seen this error before but only when I'm referencing a folder or file that doesn't exist. The images that I am trying to display are on the Desktop. I can run the same command that is in the call to `exec` from any location in the CLI and it works. I'm not real sure why it's not working from my Java application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I appreciate the comeback ;-) Is there anything I could add to also make the answer upvote worthy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: the "*" wildcard (or any other wildcard) is a feature of the underlying **shell**. Therefore it works when you use it manually on the command line.

But when using it via the process builder, there is no shell. Thus there is no component that turns the asterisk into a list of file names. Thus that string is passed as file name, and of course, there is no such file!

You either have to write Java code that expands the wildcard in code (to then pass a list of file names directly) or you have to actually start a shell explicitly (getting that right, with all the commands might be quite tricky).